# $S$ a distribution with compact support, $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}$ then :$y\mapsto\langle S,\phi(.+y)\rangle\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}$

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

I have a problem in proving the existence of a convolution product of two distributions $T,S\in \mathcal{D}^{′}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $S$ with compact support, that is to say: the linear form defined on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by
$$
\phi\mapsto  \langle T*S, \phi\rangle = \langle T_x \otimes S_y, (x,y)\mapsto \phi(x + y)\rangle
$$

In a stage of the proof he tells us that : if  $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the function :
$$
y\mapsto  \langle S, x\mapsto \phi(x + y)\rangle
$$
is an element of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I did not understand why. An idea, please.

Comment: That doesn't look correct unless $S$ has compact support.

Comment: Yes, $S$ has compact support. I corrected my mistake. Thank you

Comment: But why do we have this result?

Comment: Is your doubt about both differentiability and compact support?